# What is the best way to validate that a specific option has been selected in an asp:ListBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:ListBox that contains multiple values. A user is required to always select one specific item in this box as well as optionally selecting others.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think non of the ASP.Net validators fits your requirement out-of-the-box, what you need is to use the `CustomValdiator` and write server and client code to perform your validation

Example:

### ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientValidate(sender, args) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        $("#" + sender.controltovalidate + " option:selected").each(function (index, item) {
            if ($(this).text() == "QuestionText1") {
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
        });
    }
</script>


    <asp:ListBox runat="server"
        SelectionMode="Multiple" ID="lb" AppendDataBoundItems="false"
        DataTextField="QuestionText" DataValueField="ID"
     >
        <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
    </asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:CustomValidator ErrorMessage="errormessage" ControlToValidate="lb"
        ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate"
        OnServerValidate="cv_ServerValidate"
        runat="server" ID="cv" />
    <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" />
```

### Code Behind

```
    protected void cv_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
        foreach (ListItem item in this.lb.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                if (item.Text.ToLower().Trim() == "questiontext1")
                {
                    e.IsValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. What is the point of the code behind validation if there is JavaScript validation? Is this just in case the JavaScript fails to validate correctly for whatever reason?

Comment: Because users could disable JavaScript in their browsers and therefore bypass the validaiton. It's always a best practice to validate in the client and in the server

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is do some javascript validation on submit of the form and then do server side validation to make sure that what they submitted is valid.

You can also accomplish this with a custom validation control and then just check to make sure that the page is valid on post back.